# SQLite db not writable

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have a pre-populated SQLite db created with the Firefox SQLite Manager plugin.
I have included the DB to my project, added to the target and copied into destination group's folder. Then I created this function to copy the DB in the Documents folder:

```
-(void) createEditableDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *writableDB = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
    if (success){
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    error = nil;
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writableDB error:&error];
    if (!success){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

then I call this function in `-(void)viewDidLoad` and if I check in the simulator folder, a copy of the DB appears once I start the app.
The app runs fine, I can populate a `UICollectionView` with the data retrieved from the DB.
Then, when I try to insert some data, I receive no error but no data is added to the DB.
This is the code I use in `MyViewController.h` :

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *DBPath;
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *myAppSQLITE;
```

This is the code I use in `MyViewController.m` :

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
    DBPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    const char *dbpath = [DBPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myAppSQLITE) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO myTable (name, age) VALUES('frank',30);"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myAppSQLITE, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(myAppSQLITE);
    }
}
```

I receive no error/warning but the data is never updated, even with a `[self.collectionView reloadData];`. If I run the same query with SQLite Manager in Firefox, everything works fine.  If i open the DB inside the Simulator Documents folder with SQLite Manager, the DB is intact with no updated data. I have the same result running the app with my iPad.
How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance.

P.S: David's suggestion is right, this is a better way to create an editable DB:

```
- (void) createEditableDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success){
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

P.S2: this could be an appropriate error checking, let me know if it's right or not.

```
int rc;
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW){
    NSLog(@"ROW");
}
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE){
    NSLog(@"%s: step error: %d: %s", __FUNCTION__, rc, sqlite3_errmsg(myAppSQLite));
}
```

Comment: Just for the record, the preferred way to find the documents directory is `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually execute the query by calling `sqlite3_step`.

You want:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myAppSQLITE, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    sqlite3_step(statement); // add appropriate error checking
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I don't know how I couldn't notice the missing sqlite3_step in the last hour :) however if you modify your answer with `sqlite3_step(statement)` I will accept your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Oops - I can't believe I put the database instead of the statement. Fixed.

Comment: Had to login and thank you... Had no idea about sqlite3_step and why it was needed. Thank you! Tried to figure this out for several hours xD